# React - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to render a map that shows multiple marks with the leaflet lib, for this I tried to store multiple addresses in localStorage and then get them back and render all the marks with an array.map, but in the end all that appears in the console are three errors, the main line being "react-dom.development.js:22839 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat')".

**Map component index.tsx:**

```
function Map({positions, center}: MapProps) {
  return (
    <MapContainerStyled center={center} zoom={13}>
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      {
        positions.map(({lat, long}, index) => {
          return ( 
            <MarkerStyled position={[lat, long]} key={index}>
              <PopupStyled>
              </PopupStyled>
            </MarkerStyled>
          )
        })
      }
        <PopupStyled>
        </PopupStyled>
      
    </MapContainerStyled>
  );
}

export {Map};
```

**Function to create/add addresses to localStorage**

```
function NewStore() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, setValue, reset} = useForm();
  let stores: object[] = [];
  if(localStorage.getItem("stores")){
    stores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("stores") || "{}");
  }

  function onSubmit(data: StoreProps) {
    stores = [...stores, data]
    localStorage.setItem("stores", JSON.stringify(stores))
  }
```

**Page with the Map rendering:**

```
function StoresMap () {

  const [stores, setStores] = useState<StoreProps[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const load = async() => {
    const response = await localStorage.getItem("stores");
    setStores(JSON.parse(response!))
    }
    load()
  }, [])
  
  if(stores?.length == 0) {
    return (
      <>
      <h1>Nenhuma loja foi registrada ainda.</h1>
      <a style={{color: 'blue'}} href="/cadastro-farmacia">Clique aqui</a> para registrar uma loja.
      </>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Map positions={stores} center={[stores[0].lat, stores[0].long]}/>
    </>
  )
}

export {StoresMap}
```

**Console error:**

```
react-dom.development.js:22839 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat')
    at Object.project (Projection.SphericalMercator.js:24:43)
    at Object.latLngToPoint (CRS.js:28:40)
    at NewClass.project (Map.js:982:27)
    at NewClass.latLngToLayerPoint (Map.js:1004:29)
    at NewClass._updatePosition (DivOverlay.js:298:23)
    at NewClass.update (DivOverlay.js:189:8)
    at NewClass.onAdd (DivOverlay.js:113:8)
    at NewClass.onAdd (Popup.js:135:30)
    at NewClass._layerAdd (Layer.js:114:8)
    at NewClass.whenReady (Map.js:1477:13)
project @ Projection.SphericalMercator.js:24
latLngToPoint @ CRS.js:28
project @ Map.js:982
latLngToLayerPoint @ Map.js:1004
_updatePosition @ DivOverlay.js:298
update @ DivOverlay.js:189
onAdd @ DivOverlay.js:113
onAdd @ Popup.js:135
_layerAdd @ Layer.js:114
whenReady @ Map.js:1477
addLayer @ Layer.js:172
openOn @ DivOverlay.js:63
openOn @ Popup.js:131
addPopup @ Popup.js:30
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24926
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24891
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24878
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24866
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26935
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26117
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26959
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25981
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
```

I've tried to deal with all the typing errors and so, but in the end it didn't change.